# SVG element not rendering

Tags: svg, vue.js

I have a Vue Cli 3 project and I am trying to use vue-svgicon npm package I have followed all the steps in this tutorial: https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/dynamically-loading-svg-icons-with-vue/
but when I come to inspect the expected svg element it is not displaying in the DOM despite being present in the inspector in Google Chrome - any help is appreciated.

```
 <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="svg-icon svg-fill" 
 style="height: 3em;"></svg>
```

I installed vue-svgicon via npm then ran the script to parse the svg into javascript. Then:

```
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import './styles/global.scss';
import * as svgicon from 'vue-svgicon';

Vue.use(svgicon);


new Vue({
 router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
 }).$mount('#app')
```

Then in the component I wanted to add the SVG I added the following:

```
 <template>
     <div>
     <svgicon name="bin" height="3em"></svgicon>
   </template>

 <script>

 export default {

}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "../styles/home.scss"; 

</style>
```

Comment: could you share what have you tried so far?

Comment: the markup above has no content to render. <svg> is simply a container element.

Comment: Have you created the SVG elements dynamically? Or at least have you set any attribute in Javascript? Because what you explain happens when using `document.createElement` instead of `document.createElementNS`